# How to display WatiForm while executing method Async-Await

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

In my c# winforms application, while displaying the form I am loading the data in **LoadDataAsync** method, but before loading the data I want to start displaying the Splash Screen, which is not happening can someone guide me what I am doing wrong...or any ideas.

```
 public partial class DepartmentListDetailView : BaseForm
    {
        private DepartmentDataScope _departmentDataScope;
        private AppConfigDataScope _appConfigDataScope;
        private DepartmentSearch _departmentSearch;

        public DepartmentListDetailView() : base()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Init();
        }

        private async void Init()
        {
            _departmentDataScope = new DepartmentDataScope();
            _appConfigDataScope = new AppConfigDataScope();
            _departmentSearch = new DepartmentSearch();
            var res = await LoadDataAsync();
        }        

        private async Task<bool> LoadDataAsync()
        {
            Ssm.ShowWaitForm(); // before loading the data, I want to display the spalsh screen           

            var result = await _departmentDataScope.FetchDataAsync();
            BbiSearch.Enabled = true;
            if (Ssm.IsSplashFormVisible)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) Ssm.CloseWaitForm);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Show it before calling the async method like below code.

```
       Ssm.ShowWaitForm();
       var res = await LoadDataAsync();
       if (Ssm.IsSplashFormVisible)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) Ssm.CloseWaitForm);
        }
```